# When clutch full disengaged and engine on high revs, feeling of friction in clutch

Tags: clutch, kia, acceleration

Today I was driving my KIA cee'd 1.0 T-GDI. I was standing on a traffic light and the street was empty. So I decided to have a little fun with my car and accelerate as fast as I can. The car was fully warmed up.

My revs goes up to 8k so I decided to shift at 5k-6k.
When I disengaged the clutch fully, I felt some sort of friction like the clutch disc was rubbing against something.

As I remember, this should not be the case.
Correct me if I'm wrong but is there a problem with the clutch?

Comment: Meaning there was still something dragging on the clutch when you had the clutch pedal to the floor? Were you able to shift smoothly or was their grinding?

Comment: How were you feeling the friction? How were you detecting it?

Comment: I was able to shift smoothly.

I felt the friction through the pedal in my foot.

Comment: When you say "fully disengaged", you are suggesting with your foot on the pedal with it all the way to the floor?

Comment: Absolutely correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons for things like this.. But sometimes what you describe can happen if the release bearings internal bearings are worn or slightly oval, especially if you're stamping on the clutch pedal trying to change gear very quickly. What happens is the front face of the release bearing doesn't rotate smoothly like it's supposed to when it hits the clutches cover springs/fingers, so the bearing face actually skids slightly around the clutch cover springs giving a grindy type feel through the pedal.

Also if the spigot bearing is loose or worn, at high RPM's or certain frequencies the clutch pressure plate can vibrate on the input shaft knocking either the clutches machined face or flywheel, or both giving a weird pedal feel.

Engine harmonics can also effect the feel of the clutch pedal at specific engine/clutch/gearbox RPM's causing vibration or changes in pedal feel, which at any other RPM wouldn't be noticed. Sometimes dampers are fitted in the clutch operating mechanisms to help cure these issues.

If the problem persists though It should be checked out further.

Comment: It's a pretty new car and I've driven only about 3000km. Mostly I'm standing in a stop and go traffic to work and sometimes on weekends I drive some mountain roads (REV match on downshifts ;D).
So I don't know if there should be this much of wear.
But your last point seems reasonable cause it's a 1l 3 cylinder and there is more vibration on those types of engine.

Comment: And I don't feel any thing between 1k and 4.5k RPM's.

Comment: Clutches can get rather hot in stop/go traffic, this does of course depend a lot on RPMs used to get going each time.. But if you can set off with almost only tickover RPMs each time the clutch will be fine. High revs & fast launches though will and do take their toll on clutches, so the less it happens the longer it will be trouble free.

Comment: Of course I don't do that in traffic. I rev max 2k in traffic just to drive better off.